# Configuring Identity, efcore and Dbcontext for .Net Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, ef-core-2.1

I'm still trying to get used to the updated framework. You have to create a whole new context just for your user class like this?

```
public class ApplicationContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
  public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options)
     : base(options) {}

}
```

Can I just add the rest of my DbSet<> to the same class? I don't like the idea of creating two Context classes on the same project.

Comment: Yes, you can add your other entities to the same class.  Some people like to separate Identity from the app, run a separate Identity Server with it's own database.  You're the developer so you can organise your code how you like.

Comment: Thanks @Brad One more question. A new DbContext will also require a new ConnectionString, am I correct?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Having multiple databases will require a connection string for each database.  It's also possible to have multiple `DbContext` all working on the one database.

Comment: Oh! So I just have to add services.AddIdentity<> for the identity and services.AddDbContext<> for the other classes in the Startup class?